# Conditional formatting using IF function to meet 3 criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a row of dates at the top of my work sheet. I want to conditional format cells to give me a coloured cell **if** the date at the top of my worksheet (`H8`) is >= a date in cell `D11`, <= a date in cell `E11` (so essentially if date at the top falls between or is equal to the dates in cells `D11` & `E11`), and also cell `G11` has the word `confirmed`.

I can get it to work for just assessing the dates but can't seem to work in the third criteria that cell `G11` contains the word `confirmed`. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using a formula for the rule, you need an AND() function to combine the different conditions. If you are setting up the rule for row 11, select a cell in row 11 and use this formula in the rule

```
=AND($H$8 >= $D11, $H$8 <= $E11, $G11="confirmed")
```

Comment: My goodness that was so simple yet I just couldn't get it... thanks very much :)